# WPF MVVM - Search view functionality before presenting actual view model

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF and started learning it recently. I have a requirement and am trying to figure out what is the proper way to do it in WPF/MVVM.

Our application has 5 views (similar to pages/components in an Angular/web app). Before we can present the actual view model based on menu selection, we need to conduct a product search and have the product information stored somewhere in the context of the main window. Some views doesnt require product context

I can think of two options

1. somehow figure out that the actual selected view requires product context and present a product search view, conduct a search, and on success navigate/redirect to the corresponding view.
2. Include a search view as a control on each view, and hide the actual page view on load until the search is finished, then hide the search control.

   Product Details

   ```
    <controls:ProductSearchView Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding ProductSearchViewModel}"></controls:ProductSearchView>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   ```

I just need some general guidelines or an overall concept so that i can research and implement. Any reference to articles or similar questions is much appreciated. thanks

Comment: From the description. Main viewmodel could have current product. I recommend viewmodel first for navigation. Currentviewmodel in mainviewmodel switched out to viewmodel for any of your 5 views. Template that out into ui. User control for each of the 5 views. You would need to pass in your current product to those and maybe that object should also go in your di container.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am already learning how to layout the UI. My questions is how to change a view model (in this case main 5 views) after presenting them with the Search view. otherwise should i have both views as controls and show/hide them. Andys answer corresponds to my question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a Grid with two elements:

- ContentControl
- Product search user control

When you click an option within a menu, a destination view is loaded (into ContentControl) but product search UserControl overlaps it when a view declared that product search needs to take place first.

Create a base class that defines a single view

```
abstract class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Views ViewName { get; set; }
    private bool _productSearch;
    public bool ProductSearch
    {
        get => _productSearch;
        set
        {
            _productSearch = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand SearchProductCommand { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        SearchProductCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ProductSearch = false);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

and classes that implement base class

```
class PaymentsViewModel : ProductViewModel
{ 
    public PaymentsViewModel()
    {
        ViewName = Views.Payments;
        ProductSearch = true;
    }
}

class OrdersViewModel : ProductViewModel
{
    public OrdersViewModel()
    {
        ViewName = Views.Orders;
        ProductSearch = false;
    }
}
```

Then enum with view types (menu options)

```
enum Views
{ 
    Orders,
    Payments
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:MainViewModel}">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:OrdersViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="Orders control to be implemented"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:PaymentsViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="Payments control to be implemented"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Views}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedView}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedView}"/>
        <local:Search DataContext="{Binding SelectedView}">
            <local:Search.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProductSearch}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </local:Search.Style>
        </local:Search>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and its view-model

```
class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> Views { get; set; }
    private ProductViewModel _selectedView;
    public ProductViewModel SelectedView
    {
        get => _selectedView;
        set
        {
            _selectedView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Views = new ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>
        {
           new PaymentsViewModel(),
           new OrdersViewModel()
        };
    }
}
```

set DataContext of MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

and user control of search bar

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.Search"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         Background="White"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:ProductViewModel}">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Product search"/>
    <TextBox/>
    <Button Content="Search" Command="{Binding SearchProductCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The application looks as follows:
[image]
When I click payments option, it opens up a search bar as PaymentsViewModel has ProductSearch set to true. Once search is done, I click a search button and search control is closed and destionation view is displayed, yet to be implemented by you.